# Why am I getting different answer for same algorithm on R studio desktop vs R studio cloud?

Tags: r, linear-algebra, apple-m1

I run this simple code from class on my R studio desktop(M1 pro MacBook Pro) and the answer is different to the answer I get on R studio cloud. On the MacBook, I get 239.3093 vs 237.7821 on cloud. Am I missing something?

```
A = matrix(NA,nrow = 50,ncol = 50)
for (i in 1:50) {
  for (j in 1:50) {
    A[i,j] = sin(i) + cos(j)
  }
}

pivot.above = function(A, r, c) {
  A[r, ] = A[r, ]/A[r,c]
  for (i in (r-1):1) {
    A[i, ] = A[i, ]-A[i,c]*A[r, ]
  }
   A
}

for (i in 0:48) {
  j = 50-i
  A = pivot.above(A,j,j)
}

A[1, ] = A[1, ]/A[1,1]

print(sum(A))
```

Comment: I get 237.7821 on my Windows system

Comment: I can replicate the 239.3093 on my MacBook (M1 pro).

Comment: What is the R version number you are using on the mac?

Comment: I used version 4.1.2

Comment: 237.7821 on Windows (R 4.1.2)

Comment: 237.7821 on PopOS! Linux, R Under development (unstable) (2022-02-25 r81818)

Comment: @Jayy what happens if you run the code in my answer below?

Comment: 237.7821 on Windows

Comment: @MrFlick Build 443

Comment: @DaveArmstrong I get 239.3093

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This matrix has a very large *condition number*. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number#Matrices):

> If the condition number is very large, then the matrix is said to be ill-conditioned. Practically, such a matrix is almost singular, and the computation of its inverse, or solution of a linear system of equations is prone to large numerical errors.

```r
kappa(A)
[1] 1.352794e+19
```

This means that *tiny* numerical differences, such as the difference between compilers, system linear algebra libraries, operating systems, chips, etc., will lead to non-negligible differences in the results — as you found out.

As @DaveArmstrong commented, what the OP is doing here is not *exactly* either of the operations mentioned in the Wikipedia article (inversion or solution of a linear system); we're reducing the matrix to lower triangular form by Gaussian elimination. However, they're closely related (once we've reduced the matrix to triangular form, we've done most of the work of solving a linear system, because we can now use simple back-substitution). I don't know offhand why the sum of the first column of the reduced matrix should be a quantity that is especially sensitive, but it's not surprising to me that the condition number is related to this sensitivity. In [these notes](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/%7Eluke/classes/STAT7400-2020/modules/mod_linalg.pdf), Luke Tierney (an R-core member ...) describes why simple Gaussian elimination is unstable, and why a more sophisticated *partial pivoting* approach is more stable.

This is a perfectly reasonable question to ask, but is also  something you're going to have to learn about/get used to as you move ahead with numerical computation. It would actually be a great thing to ask your instructor about.

Comment: I can understand that this could lead to differences in finding the inverse or something like that, but the operation above is just adding some numbers together.  Whether those numbers come from an ill-conditioned matrix or a vector (where ill-conditioning is presumably not an issue), shouldn't the answer be the same? That is `sum(c(A))` shouldn't have any of the ill-conditioning problems, but it produces the same result.

Comment: I haven't looked in detail at the linear algebra you're doing, to be honest.  But the code above isn't just adding numbers ... can you edit your question to include the operations you say "shouldn't have any of the ill-conditioning problems" ?

Comment: This isn't my question - I was just curios.  I posted an answer that shows my thinking that there is no linear algebra in the problem - only vectorized scalar arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks,  my mistake.  I guess the point is that, at root, all linear algebra is just sets of scalar arithmetic organized in a particular way (e.g. Gaussian elimination is just a specified set of rules for adding and subtracting scalar multiples of rows of a matrix, which boils down to a bunch of scalar arithmetic).

Comment: Sorry to be dense, but then does that mean this isn't an ill-conditioned matrix problem?  Or is it that ill-conditioning is a symptom of some more general problem?  Is it at all related to the floating point issue that gets discussed with some frequency on SO?

Comment: I don't think you're being dense at all. This operation is doing row reduction to get to a triangular matrix. I don't know offhand why the sum of the first column of the reduced matrix should be a quantity that is especially sensitive, but it's not surprising to me that the condition number is related to the sensitivity. This page http://homepage.stat.uiowa.edu/~luke/classes/STAT7400-2021/_book/numerical-linear-algebra.html by Luke Tierney (an R-core member ...) describes why simple Gaussian elimination can be unstable, and why a more sophisticated *partial pivoting* approach  is more stable.

Comment: More generally, ill-conditioning is a special case of *numerical instability*. Numerical instability + floating-point error = bad news, and since floating-point error is ubiquitous (as long as we're doing finite-precision arithmetic), numerical instability = bad news

Comment: Thanks, Ben!  Your intervention here is enlightening as always.

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you for this! Very insightful. I'm going to have to look into "condition numbers" because I'm not familiar with this. And it was my instructor who actually advised me to post this here because he wasn't sure why this happened (turns out another student on the M1 pro got the same result).

Answer (score 1):

Apologies that this isn't really an answer, but perhaps it's somewhere to start.  In response to Ben's response to my question, I understand that the algorithm isn't just adding numbers, but so far as I can see, it is just vectorized scalar arithmetic (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division) - there are no matrix operations going on.  The fact that the inputs and outputs are organized in a matrix is incidental.  Consider what I think is an equivalent set of operations for data organized in a rectangular data frame rather than a square matrix.

```r
B <- expand.grid(
  row = 1:50, 
  col = 1:50)

B <- B %>% 
  mutate(A = sin(row) + cos(col))
```

I rewrote the `pivot.above` function to work for this long-form data:

```r
pivot.above.long <- function(A, rowind, colind){
  A$A[which(A$row == rowind)]  <- A$A[which(A$row == rowind)]/A$A[which(A$row == rowind & A$col == colind)]
  for(i in (rowind - 1):1){
    A$A[which(A$row == i)] = A$A[which(A$row == i)]-A$A[which(A$row == i & A$col == colind)]*A$A[which(A$row == rowind)]
  }
  A
}
```

Then, I applied that to the long-form data:

```r
for (i in 0:48) {
  j = 50-i
  B = pivot.above.long(B,j,j)
}

B$A[which(B$row == 1)] <- B$A[which(B$row == 1)]/B$A[which(B$row == 1 & B$col == 1)]
```

And, I get exactly the same result as I got from the matrix operations - one of the two values returned in the original question.

```
print(sum(B$A))
# [1] 239.3093
```

Comment: I get 239.3093, same as yours